# Корзина сбрасывается ровно через час [OpenCart 2]

Tags: php, сессия, opencart

Стоит opencart, нужно чтобы корзина не сбрасывалась сутки, так как заказы очень большие и долго добавляют. Уже сделал все возможное, но корзина все равно сбрасывается.

1. **На сервере установлено**

   session.cookie_lifetime 86400;
   session.gc_maxlifetime 86400;
2. **В php.ini в корневой папке:**

   magic_quotes_gpc = Off;

   register_globals = Off;

   default_charset = UTF-8;

   memory_limit = 1024M;

   session.cookie_lifetime 86400;

   session.gc_maxlifetime 86400;

   php_value session.cache_expire 180;

   php_value max_execution_time = 36000;

   upload_max_filesize = 4000M;

   php_value max_input_vars = 10000;

   php_value suhosin.request.max_vars = 10000;

   php_value suhosin.post.max_vars = 10000;

   safe_mode = Off;

   mysql.connect_timeout = 20;

   session.auto_start = Off;

   session.use_only_cookies = On;

   session.use_cookies = On;

   session.use_trans_sid = Off;

   session.cookie_httponly = On;

   allow_url_fopen = on;

**Изменил файл session.php | вывел в отдельную папку, дал права 700**

```
public function __construct($session_id = '',  $key = 'default') {
    if (!session_id()) {
        ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 'Off');
        ini_set('session.use_cookies', 'On');
        ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 'Off');
        ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 'On');

        if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\-]{22,40}$/', $_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            exit();
        }

        if ($session_id) {
            session_id($session_id);
        }
        session_set_cookie_params(86400, '/');
        ini_set('session.cache_expire', '180');
        ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', '86400');
        session_save_path(realpath(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/session'));
        session_start();
    }

    if (!isset($_SESSION[$key])) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = array();
    }

    $this->data =& $_SESSION[$key];
}
```

**Добавил правило еще и в .htaccess**

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 86400
```

Даже после этого корзина сбрасывается ровно через час.

Comment: Проблема решена так: Переходим \system\library\cart.php и там видим: `$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE customer_id = '0' AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");` изменяем **INTERVAL 1 HOUR** на сколько нам нужно :)

Answer (score 1):

Для опенкарта 2.2:
здесь /system/library/session.php меняем значение в строке

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
```

на

```
session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24, '/');
```

А также вот здесь:  /system/library/cart/cart.php
меняем значение в строке `$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE customer_id = '0' AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");`
на вот такое:

```
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "cart WHERE customer_id = '0' AND date_added < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");
```

Для других версий примерно такая-же процедура. Пути могут немного отличаться.